# how to run a POST http request with parameter in nifi using processor invokeHTTP

Tags: apache-nifi

I search a lot on the internet but havent found appropriate answer for my question.
I have a curl command that looks like that :

```
curl -X POST --data-binary 'query=select ?s ?p ?o where {?s ?p ?o} limit 10' https://your-neptune-endpoint:port/sparql
```

I wanted to know in which field i can add the query parameter and its value in the invokeHTTP processor, because i tried many ways but in vain
One of my approach was to create a generateFlowFile with this content :

```
query=select ?s ?p ?o where {?s ?p ?o} limit 10'
```

and the output is redirected to a invokehttp processor but i got this error

```
invokehttp.response.body
{"detailedMessage":"Missing 'query' or 'update' parameter for POST request","code":"MissingParameterException","requestId":"64bf26c2-31ab-1ee2-df39-793e0abb0d0e"}
```

Any idea?

Comment: In general you are doing it right. Add -v param to curl. It will print all headers it sends to server. Then you have to add the same to invokehttp.

Comment: it's not resolving the problem :( can you give me more detail? thanks

Comment: what exactly not helped? which headers you have added into invokehttp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you have this http request:

```
> POST /sparql HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: your-neptune-endpoint:8182
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 47
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

you have to set at least following parameters for InvokeHttp nifi:

```
HTTP Method:         POST
Remote URL:          https://your-neptune-endpoint:8182/sparql
SSL Context Service: <...>
Content-Type:        application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

`Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

is declaring that parameters will be passed in format `a=v1 & b=v2 &...`

the flowfile body could be set using GenerateFlowFile before InvokeHttp

```
query=select ?s ?p ?o where {?s ?p ?o} limit 10
```

> note the unnecessary quote in body in your question

if your parameter value contains some special chars like `=` or `&` better to encode it in GenerateFlowFile:

```js
query=${'select ?s ?p ?o where {?s ?p ?o} limit 10':urlEncode()}
```